# How to configure log4j for package level logging?

Tags: log4j, flume

I want to log in to multiple log files(flume and console). How to set log4j as package level?ie com.mypackage.myclass into flume and other packages into console..

Comment: Then only thing I know is that flume doesn't support it out of the box. Take a look at flume-daemon.sh, FLUME_LOGFILE is set to a single file:

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to configure log4j to have two named loggers, one that sends to the Console appender, and one that sends to Flume. You can then write use a proxy class for making your logging calls that routes the log4j calls to the different loggers depending on the package the caller is in. You can do this by accessing the stack of the current thread, like so:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger()
    {
            // this will get the calling frame, 0=Thread, 1=this, 2=caller
            StackTraceElement stackElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
            if(stackElement.getClassName().startsWith("the.package.that.goes.to.flume"))
            {
                return org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("Flume");
            }
            else
            {
                return org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("Console");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is assuming you have named your two loggers 'Flume' and 'Console'.

When ever you make a logging call in your app, use Logger.getLogger() rather than going to log4j directly.

Comment: does this not answer your question?

Answer (score -2):

Check this blog post
http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/log4j-tutorial-adding-log4j-logging-to-your-project/

It has a complete PDF for download on how to add log4j to project.

You need to define categories for different packages.Everything is explained in above PDF.

Hope it helps.